# tensorflow import does not work

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.5, tensor

In the python shell when I type

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

the script breaks. It fails to load the native runtime. I am using python 3.5.2. Here is the error log:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
    sorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module(mname)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in impor
    t_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
    sorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
      File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
    sorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
      File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
    sorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
      File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in impor
    t_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", lin
    e 24, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import *
      File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.p
    y", line 51, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
      File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
    sorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
        raise ImportError(msg)
    ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
    sorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module(mname)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in impor
    t_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
    sorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
      File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
    sorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
      File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
    sorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
      File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in impor
    t_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


    Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: updated text for readability

Answer (score 0):

I once faced this issue and got it solved by installing the `Visual C++ Redistributable`.

Refer to this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8385) in `github`. It was quite helpful for me.